# About the output of pomegranate

Tags: python

I've now built a Bayesian network with pomeganate, and output the results for one of the nodes I want while fixing the values of several of them, as follows:

{
"class" : "Distribution",
"dtype" : "str",
"name" : "DiscreteDistribution",
"parameters" : [
{
"2" : 0.20000000000000015,
"1" : 0.3999999999999998,
"3" : 0.4
}
],
"frozen" : false
}

**But now I just want to get the value of the parameters part of it, how should I do?**

Here's the code：

```
import math
from pomegranate import *

O = DiscreteDistribution( { '1': 1./2, '2': 1./2} )
HA = DiscreteDistribution( { '1': 1./3, '2': 1./3, '3': 1./3 } )
HE = DiscreteDistribution( { '1': 1./3, '2': 1./3, '3': 1./3 } )

RE = ConditionalProbabilityTable(
    [['1', '1', '1', '1', 0.8],
     ['1', '1', '1', '2', 0.2],
     ['1', '1', '1', '3', 0.0],#1

     ['1', '1', '2', '1', 1.0],
     ['1', '1', '2', '2', 0.0],
     ['1', '1', '2', '3', 0.0],#2

     ['1', '2', '1', '1', 0.8],
     ['1', '2', '1', '2', 0.2],
     ['1', '2', '1', '3', 0.0],#3

     ['1', '2', '2', '1', 1.0],
     ['1', '2', '2', '2', 0.0],
     ['1', '2', '2', '3', 0.0],#4

     ['1', '3', '1', '1', 0.6],
     ['1', '3', '1', '2', 0.2],
     ['1', '3', '1', '3', 0.2],#5

     ['1', '3', '2', '1', 0.8],
     ['1', '3', '2', '2', 0.2],
     ['1', '3', '2', '3', 0.0],#6

     ['2', '1', '1', '1', 0.0],
     ['2', '1', '1', '2', 0.0],
     ['2', '1', '1', '3', 1.0],#7

     ['2', '1', '2', '1', 0.0],
     ['2', '1', '2', '2', 0.0],
     ['2', '1', '2', '3', 1.0],#8

     ['2', '2', '1', '1', 0.0],
     ['2', '2', '1', '2', 0.1],
     ['2', '2', '1', '3', 0.9],#9

     ['2', '2', '2', '1', 0.1],
     ['2', '2', '2', '2', 0.1],
     ['2', '2', '2', '3', 0.8],#10

     ['2', '3', '1', '1', 0.0],
     ['2', '3', '1', '2', 0.2],
     ['2', '3', '1', '3', 0.8],#11

     ['2', '3', '2', '1', 0.2],
     ['2', '3', '2', '2', 0.2],
     ['2', '3', '2', '3', 0.6],#12

     ['3', '1', '1', '1', 0.7],
     ['3', '1', '1', '2', 0.3],
     ['3', '1', '1', '3', 0.0],#13

     ['3', '1', '2', '1', 0.8],
     ['3', '1', '2', '2', 0.2],
     ['3', '1', '2', '3', 0.0],#14

     ['3', '2', '1', '1', 0.8],
     ['3', '2', '1', '2', 0.2],
     ['3', '2', '1', '3', 0.0],#15

     ['3', '2', '2', '1', 0.9],
     ['3', '2', '2', '2', 0.1],
     ['3', '2', '2', '3', 0.0],#16

     ['3', '3', '1', '1', 0.6],
     ['3', '3', '1', '2', 0.2],
     ['3', '3', '1', '3', 0.2],#17

     ['3', '3', '2', '1', 0.7],
     ['3', '3', '2', '2', 0.2],
     ['3', '3', '2', '3', 0.1]],#18
    [HE, HA, O]
)

s1 = State( O, name="object" )
s2 = State( HA, name="action" )
s3 = State( HE, name="expression" )
s4 = State( RE, name="robot" )

network = BayesianNetwork( "test" )
network.add_states( s1, s2, s3, s4)

network.add_transition( s1, s4 )
network.add_transition( s2, s4 )
network.add_transition( s3, s4 )

network.bake()

observations = { 'object' : '1', 'action':'3' }
beliefs = map( str, network.predict_proba( observations ) )

for state, belief in zip( network.states, beliefs ):
 if state==s4:
  print(belief)
```

I tried outputting the type of the result, but it says it's a str type, so I have no idea how to extract the part I want.

Comment: If the output is a str like this `"{ "class" : "Distribution", "dtype" : "str", "name" : "DiscreteDistribution", "parameters" : [ { "2" : 0.20000000000000015, "1" : 0.3999999999999998, "3" : 0.4 } ], "frozen" : false }"`, you can use `json.load()` (or `json.loads()`) to convert the string to a "useable" output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, I solved this problem with json.loads!